# RDLC Pie chart, legend to show value from database

Tags: c#, charts, rdlc, legend, pie-chart

I have a .RDLC with one pie chart designed.

The pie chart is used to display the slices of a service which we offer.

We offer 3 levels of service - 1, 2 and 3. 1 = Office demo. 2 = Trial and 3 = Full

Currently the legend shows the numbers 1, 2 and 3 with their associated colour but is it possible for them to read Office, Trial and Full instead?

I have a category field defined as LicenceType (the field name from the database table) and I have a data field defined as Count(LicenceType).

Do I need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Place an expression on the Series data like such:

```
=Switch(Fields!Data.Value = 1, "Office Demo", Fields!Data.Value = 2, "Trial", Fields!Data.Value = 3, "Full")
```

Substitute Data with the name of the column in your series.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a case statement into your SQL query to select the name into a column and then set the label formula equal to the field with your text description in it. Even better if you have the text names in the database in a join table or whatever then just update your query to pull in another column and display that column as the label formula.